# iptables: refuse immediately when blocking particular domain from visiting by browser

Tags: iptables

I need to block particular domain "megafonpro.ru" and all subdomains from visiting by browser.

Here's rule that I wrote:

```
sudo iptables -I OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -m string --string "megafonpro.ru" --algo kmp --to 65535 -j REJECT
```

It works, but not perfect: when I try to enter matching URL (say, "wap.megafonpro.ru"), firefox tries to connect for very long time (about 30 seconds), and then reports "The connection was reset". How to make it refuse immediately?

---

**UPD:** I found out that I can just add non-wanted domains to the `/etc/hosts`, like that:

```
127.0.0.1   megafonpro.ru
127.0.0.1   m.megafonpro.ru
127.0.0.1   wap.megafonpro.ru
```

We can't wildcard sumdomains unfortunately ( related question: https://serverfault.com/questions/118378/in-my-etc-hosts-file-on-linux-osx-how-do-i-do-a-wildcard-subdomain ). Now, browser refuses immediately.

But anyway, I'm interested how to make it with iptables.

Comment: Cleanest way i've found so far is to use `dnsmasq` for this, see [this one](http://askubuntu.com/questions/150135/how-to-block-specific-domains-in-hosts-file/150180#150180).

Answer (score 0):

When you put those lines in /etc/hosts you are actually telling that the IP address for those name is 127.0.0.1 (note that if a web server is running on localhost, it will display).

To do the same with iptables you need to use destination NAT (and it has to be done on PREROUTING section I think).
The advantage over putting it in /etc/hosts is that it also works for routed packets (and not only those originating on the same host)